# Binding Angular Service to Scope fails after 1.2 update

Tags: angularjs, promise

I've tried to strip out the details and make this fairly generalized...

Using 1.2 rc2 my code worked fine, after updating to 1.2 stable and correcting for $parse changes I've run into a binding problem. Before the update, the following code worked without any issues. `updateChildObject()` gets called from the html page.

```
.when('/the-page/', {
  controller: function($scope, serviceResults, FactoryService) {
    $scope.object.childObject = serviceResults;

    // this function used to work. Now assigns the function to the 
    // scope rather than the results
    $scope.updateChildObject = function(args) {
      $scope.object.childObject = FactoryService.getSomethingFromServer(args);
    };

  },
  resolve: {
    serviceResults: function(FactoryService) {
      return FactoryService.getSomethingFromServer(args);
    }
  }
```

Since this is failing now ($scope.object.childObject appears to get set as the function and not the results) I believe the appropriate way to solve it is through a promise. (Note, the service itself is using a promise successfully.) However, I'm having difficulty getting the $scope to update when the promise is resolved.

I believe the following code is along the right track. $q is injected in the controller.

```
...
$scope.updateChildObject = function(args) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  defer.promise.then(function() {
    return FactoryService.getSomethingFromServer(args);
  });
  $scope.object.childObject = defer.resolve();
};
...
```

So can anyone tell my what I'm doing wrong here? Promises are just one of those things that haven't really clicked for me yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an alternative to your answer: you say FactoryService is already successfully using a promise, and in that case it seems like you don't need an additional promise in `updateChildObject` too. You could update `FactoryService.getSomethingFromServer(args)` to return a promise (i.e. with `return defer.promise;` at the end and `defer.resolve(results);` in the async bit), and then simplify `updateChildObject` to just:

```
$scope.updateChildObject = function(args) {
  FactoryService.getSomethingFromServer(args).then(function(results) {
     $scope.object.childObject = results;
  }
};
```

Also, it's worth knowing that Angular 1.2 intentionally breaks automatic promise unwrapping that was in earlier versions: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4158 . It used to be the case that this code

```
$scope.updateChildObject = function(args) {
     $scope.object.childObject = FactoryService.getSomethingFromServer(args);
};
```

would work identically to the one above (assuming getSomethingFromServer returns a promise), but not anymore. This might be the issue you're running into with 1.2

Comment: Ah man, thanks for the tip. No idea I could use my service like that. Really helpful. So both versions seem to work equally as well. Your model eliminates the need for injecting $q which I like. You're right though, the automatic unwrapping was exactly what I was running in to.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. Definitely was a promise issue in that I just wasn't using them correctly. The following solved it:

```
...
$scope.updateChildObject = function(args) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.promise.then(function(results) {
        $scope.object.childObject = results;
    });
    defer.resolve(FactoryService.getSomethingFromServer(args));
};
...
```

So defer.resolve calls what's to be resolved. promise.then() passes the results to the next action. So simple.